# How to stub a method used in a Sinatra app with Minitest?

Tags: sinatra, stub, minitest

I want to test a small Sinatra application. And to do so, stub out some behaviour.

The relevant code in the Sinatra app is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'yaml'

get '/commands' do
  YAML.load_file("commands.yml")["commands"].join("\n")
end
```

The `minitest/spec` code to test that is:

```
include Rack::Test::Methods
def app
  Sinatra::Application
end

describe "/commands" do
  describe "with two commands defined" do
    it "must list the two commands" do
      YAML.stub(:load_file, {"commands" => ["hostname", "uptime"]}) do
        get '/commands'
        last_response.must_be :ok?
        last_response.body.must_equal "hostname\nuptime"
      end
    end
  end
  describe "with no commands defined" do
    YAML.stub(:load_file, {"commands" => nil}) do
      it "must list no commands" do
        get '/commands'
        last_response.body.must_equal ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using a small spec_helper:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'rack/test'

require_relative '../minion' #This is the sinatra-app.
```

The `YAML.stub` part is the most important, as it does not [work as expected](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/#label-Stubs). It does stub out `YAML.load_file` inside the spec just fine. But in the context of the sinatra-app, `YAML.load_file` is unstubbed and loads the `commands.yml`, despite my attempt to stub it out.

How can I stub out a call to `YAML.load_file` with `minitest/spec` and have that stub being used in the Sinatra application?